# After renaming solution/projects, ASP.NET IIS is looking in the wrong (old) location for the config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, config, rename, configuration-files

I get the error: "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

[image: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.vs` folder (should be in the same directory as your .sln file).  Visual Studio will recreate it with the correct paths.